# atmega64 rx interrupt not working while enc28j60 connected

Tags: atmega

ENC28J60 is connected with ATMega64. All functions are working fine except Rx interrupt in microcontroller.
When I am enabling receive USART interrupt adding

```
 UCSR1B |= (1 << RXCIE1);
```

Microcontroller is rebooting with a time interval.

Answer (score 0):

I guess : wrong vector table or power problems. You have to provide the code, schematics and how you power the micro & ENC...